# .htaccess Redirect Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with some redirects on the redesign of a website.
The old one got several urls like this:

```
http://www.example.com/sitegroup/pages/GA/GA_Be.shtml
```

And I want to redirect this to:

```
http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenforum-ideengarten
```

I tried it with the following rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?pagesGA/GA_Be.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenforum-ideengarten$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

But I just can't get it working.. I'm really new to .htaccess rewriterules.

Also some of the old pages got links like this:

```
http://www.example.com/sitegroup/pages/GA/GA_Be.shtml?navid=15
```

But the ?navid=15 isn't doing something(just highlighting the menulink) so I thought just redirecting the GA_BE.shtml should be enough. Am I correct?

Here is the complete .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitegroup/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sitegroup/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^/?pagesGA/GA_Be.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenforum-ideengarten$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your `RewriteRule` before Wordpress Dispatcher:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sitegroup/
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_Be\.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenforum-ideengarten [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_Bg\.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenplanung-landsc‌​haftsplanung [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_En\.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#erdsondenbohrung-erd‌​waerme [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sitegroup/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /sitegroup/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Otherwise the request will first be handled by the Dispatcher and never reach your rule.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working!
But if I want to redirect more page, it's just wokring with the first one..
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sitegroup/
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_Be.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenforum-ideengarten [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_Bg.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#gartenplanung-landschaftsplanung [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^pages/GA/GA_En.shtml$ http://www.example.com/sitegroup/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#erdsondenbohrung-erdwaerme [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: Could you please accept this answer to mark the question as solved? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I will ;) But can u help me with my comment above? Only the first rule get executed :(

Comment: Sorry didn't see your edit ;). It should be working, I can't see any mistakes in those rules.

Comment: Hey it is still just working for the first rule :(
Ok this was just from copieing directly from Excel ;)